# Xamarin.Forms button positioning

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im having a very hard time to design my simple UI without a Designer on Xamarin.Forms for Android.Im trying to learn about Xamarin.Forms
To get a Picture for what im trying to do i got a Screenshot, thats what i tried so far:

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">

  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Image Source="Login.png"/>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="End">
    <Button Text="Start"/>
    <Button Text="Login"/>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

EDIT: With my Code im getting 2 small buttons at the Buttom and, i dont know why, can you just guide me in the right direction. Just want to know how i can position my controls to look like the screenshot

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question.

Comment: Because bottom `StackLayout` fills exactly what it need, but middle `StackLayout` takes all free space, because you set `VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand`.

Comment: Thanks, so should i get rid of the middle stacklayout ?

Comment: it would help if you also posted an image of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I did ... look at the screenshot.

Comment: sorry, I thought that was a shot of what you were actually getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Image/>

  <Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks im trieng this right now, never thought of Grids :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Why your stackpanel for buttons have vertical orientation? This will place them one under another;
2. You can try setting the stackpanel's horizontal alignment to Stretch;
3. I think using the Grid will be a better approach (look at Egor's answer)